# Css / React speech bubble widget

Tags: css

Hello I'm trying to make a bubble widget but I'm having problems basically I need one on top of the other like this:

[image]

but I'm not able to do anything like that
can anybody help me?

code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="WrapperChat">
        <div class="bubble" />
        <div class="bubble2 b2" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.WrapperChat {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.bubble {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #fff;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}

.bubble::after {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.4);
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 20px;
}

.bubble2 {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #fff;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}
.bubble2::after {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.4);
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  right: -60px;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
}
.b2 {
  transform: translateY(-40%);
}
```

Basically I am not able to position correctly using the translate and I cannot imagine how to make this cut of the arrow of the ballon

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-haslett-tr09n

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: absolute` in each bubble element to handle with `z-index`

```
.bubble {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #fff;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 60px;

  **position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;**
}
```

and after add `position: absolute` here you can set the `top`

```
.bubble2 {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #fff;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-snow-e6j8e

Comment: thanks could you give me some help with the bubble arrow?

Comment: I don't know how to transform the arrow like in the picture of the question]

Comment: Sorry, I could not! But, may it can helps you out, there are some examples here that maybe you can try replicate https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=message+bubbles